# Dynamic Date In E-mail Message In Outlook

Tags: vba, outlook

I am trying to edit the message of my .msg file. Basically I want my message to be:

Please find attached report for March 2019.

However, when I am in May and click on the .msg again, I want the template to open it up and say:

Please find attached report for April 2019.

I have tried the field codes:

```
If ""="", EOMONTH(TODAY(),-1)
```

Is there a way to do this without creating a macro or add-in? I would like to introduce a way to do this in the subject line and email body.

Answer (score 0):

*To get previous month Work with **[DateAdd Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/visualstudio/visual-studio-2008/hcxe65wz(v=vs.90))***

*Example*

```
Format(DateAdd("m", -1, Date), "yyyymm")
```

Comment: Hey! Sorry, this does not work for Field Codes in an outlook message. Thanks though!